# Wedge sum of circles

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, free-product

Is the wedge sum of circles considered as a path?

According to Wikipedia([Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(topology))), the figure eight graph $S^1\vee S^1$  is directed even though it is the direct sum of two circles with two points equivalent

Answer (score 2):

The second picture there has directed loops just for illustrating that they are the generators of the fundamental group of figure eight. Without such specific purpose, you don't need to understand any topological space to be directed.

Comment: One such purpose could be to understand the graph-theoretic properties of a directed graph which can also be understood as a topological space.